# JMAP -dump not excuted on java: runtime.exec()

Tags: java, unix, heap-dump, jmap

i have tried to execute the 'jmap -dump:format =b; file" command in runtime.exec(), but it wont execute where other commands like date, pwd are working fine.
can anyone know why?

public static void commands(String s)
    {

```
    runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();


    try {
        System.out.println(" Creating Heap Dump ");
        process=runtime.exec("jmap -dump:format=b,file=D:/heapdump_2012APR10/heapdump_date +%d%b%Y-%H_%M_%S.bin 4478");
        System.out.println("Heap Dump Created. Zipping the file");
        process=runtime.exec("gzip *.bin");
        System.out.println("Succesfully zipped");



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you use to call it.

Comment: A solution is probably to be found by implementing ***all*** the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call two consecutively processes

```
process=runtime.exec("jmap -dump:format=b,file=D:/heapdump_2012APR10/heapdump_date +%d%b%Y-%H_%M_%S.bin 4478");
process=runtime.exec("gzip *.bin");
```

without waiting that the first one terminates.

And then you don't ever consume the stream of the processes you exec, or check theirs exit code.

So follow the suggestion of @Andrew Thompson and read this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). It explains very well how to launch external process from Java.

Comment: Thanks,, Dash. But i got another error named "error attaching to core file can't attach to the core file". Thanks.